# How to set up Stripe API for Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

How do we set up Stripe API for Parse Cloud Code. I've managed to get the code working, but I'd like to edit it. The function below is "stripe.customers.create", it only works when I remove the source line. How can I request the token? I am also trying to connect the Stripe customer to the parse user.t

```
Parse.Cloud.define("customer", function(request, response){
stripe.customers.create({
    description: request.params.description
    //source: request.params.token
}, function(err, customer) {
    if(err){
            console.log(err);
            response.error(err);
    }
    else{
            console.log(customer);
            response.success(customer);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what goes wrong when you try and execute this code with the `source`-argument?  Is it possible that the token is merely being declined?  If it's in test-mode, you could use the `4242424242424242` card number to verify that.  I'd also make sure you remember to add a `,` (comma) at the end of your request.params.description (though I assume you did already).

Comment: @andrewnelder Thank you. I've done what you suggested and a customer is created. However, it does not link any card with the customer, although the Xcode console shows that a token is created.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this question before. You can find my [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38736382/4287861)

The idea is that in parse-server you can install any npm module that you want so in my answer i explain how you can first install the stripe npm module and then call it from your cloud code function.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the question you sent me too does not help.